# What could be the reasons that .net-core does not release large objects (under linux) right away?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have the following code snippet, that downloads an about `100mb` big zip file that then will be deserialzed into a `Foo` for further processing. This code is execcuted once per day.

```
Stream stream = await downloader.DownloadStream().ConfigureAwait(false);

if (stream.CanSeek && stream.Length == 0)
{
    throw new IOException("Error! Received stream is empty.");
}

ZipArchive archive;

try
{
    archive = new ZipArchive(stream);
}
catch (InvalidDataException)
{
    throw new IOException("Error! Received stream is no zip file.");
}

using (var reader = new StreamReader(archive.Entries[0].Open()))
{
    Foo foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(reader.ReadToEnd());
    [...]
}

archive.Dispose();
stream.Dispose();
```

Now, when that code kicks in, the memory usage jumps as high as about `2500mb`. So far so good, and I would say, pretty common.

The (maybe?) uncommon thing is, that the memory sometimes takes days to be released. Now, when running that code on multiple instances, let's say inside *k8s*, you would see the following pattern of memory usage.

[image: Memory usage over 7 days]

So you see, the memory is eventually released, so I doubt I have some error inside the code regarding a possible leak. The question is if this is expected behavior of the `clr` or if I maybe can enhance this behavior. What I already read is that this would definitely involve the large object heap. But it's hard do find internals how that heap behaves natively under linux.

So for hosting this in *k8s*, this means that I need to plan the resources for the worst case scenario, that all hosted instances will have about `2500mb` allocated.

Comment: In your graph above, what does the different colours represent? As far as I know, when it comes to memory management, objects will be GC’ed whenever it’s needed and not before.
Do you terminate the application after it’s done running or just wait for it to terminate on its own? `Environment.Exit(0)` for instance?

Comment: Each color is one instance running. The instances are running all the time.

Comment: Were you trying to call garbage collector explicitly?

Comment: No. Did not try that. Don't wanted to fiddle with automatic behavior..